# Google App Engine with JRuby - can someone provide an overview of appengine-jruby, warble etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, jruby

I'm getting myself confused as to how to get a JRuby app cranking on App Engine.

I know that you can get started using the [appengine-jruby](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/wiki/Introduction) "gem" (Note: I'm a Java programmer, so this is all completely new to me). I've also seen some talk about [Warbler](http://kenai.com/projects/warbler/pages/Home), and am getting the impression that I could probably use Warbler somehow with App Engine.

Why I'm not diving into appengine-jruby straight away is that I'm seeing some strange things like the following:

> This project uses its own customised
>   version of jruby that is packaged
>   ('frozen' in ruby speak) with the
>   other gems.

Some things I've seen about Warbler is also making me curious, e.g:

> Warbler provides a sane set of
>   out-of-the box defaults that should
>   allow most Rails applications without
>   external gem dependencies (aside from
>   Rails itself) to assemble and just
>   work.

I'm just sort of wondering what are the different ways of getting a JRuby app going on App Engine. Is there someone that could explain the big picture?

For now I think I'll just get started, and use the appengine-jruby gem.

Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRuby on App Engine requires a bunch of special gems.  A great Getting Started Guide is [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/wiki/GettingStarted).

I would also recommend following [John Woodell](http://twitter.com/johnwoodell/) on Twitter.  He's one of Googles few Ruby programmers, and speaks at a lot of conferences about running JRuby on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.nicksieger.com/files/Sieger-RailsDeployment-J12008.pdf might help
http://jruby-appengine.blogspot.com/2010/09/google-app-engine-0017-gems-released.html too

Answer (score 0):

Install the gem, then create the sample application on the getting started pages. Until everything gets updated you have to tweak a few things to make it work:

1. rubygems needs to be no later a version than 1.3.5. If it is newer, uninstall rubygem-update.
2. in the Gemfile you need to force jruby-rack to version 1.0.5 like this:
   gem "jruby-rack", "1.0.5" 
   (one user reported needing to force to 1.0.4)

Right now the framework is desperately needing an upgrade to fix a few issues like these, but as I understand, it needs to wait for bundler to be upgraded to make the jump.

Don't be afraid to send questions to the mailing list. There are lots of people willing to help.